# NODE.JS - Cannot find module '@hapi/boom'

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, nodejs-server

I've been asked to create a super simple chatbot. I'm not a developer and I've never used node.js before. I found [this simple demo](https://github.com/pvangool/rcs-maap-bot/blob/master/example/echo-express.js) on GitHub. I first ran `npm install rcs-maap-bot` as [the main page says](https://github.com/pvangool/rcs-maap-bot/tree/master), pasted the code, ran it and [I get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VQpn.png). Online research said to move its missing `index.js` so I moved copied it a directory back and now I get this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nVj3.png

I wasn't able to resolve it.

Does anyone know what's going on? Huge thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Maap`, provided that you have it on node_modules, replacing

```
const Maap = require('../')
```

wit this line should work:

```
const Maap = require('rcs-maap-bot')
```